# signalR Groups.Remove doesn't work

Tags: signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, owin

I have a [self-hosted](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host) application akin to a scenario wherein I have a method that continuously broadcasts to groups (whether somebody has "joined" or not). Something like:

```
var aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
aTimer.Elapsed += (sender, e) =>
{
  // broadcast to listeners whether they are listening or not
  IHubConnectionContext _clients = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>().Clients;

  _clients.Group("group1FixedName").showMessage("Some message for group 1 only");       
  _clients.Group("group2FixedName").showMessage("Some message for group 2 only");       
  // etc
};
aTimer.Start();
```

I had recently upgraded to version 1.1.0 from beta1. I started to observe that the "remove" method doesn't work as the ["client" (web browser)](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/SignalR-JS-Client-Hubs) is still receiving messages from the "other" group even if I initiated a "leave". Note that "leaving" the group doesn't mean closing the web browser. It's still in the same page (Single Page Application) and leaving/joining a group is triggered by a selection (combo box for example).

Code in hub:

```
public Task Leave(string groupName)
{
        return Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, groupName)
               .ContinueWith(z => Clients.Caller.showCallerMessage("You are now leaving " + groupName));

}
```

Code in javascript client to "leave the group":

```
chat.server.leave("group1FixedName");
```

Code in javascript client to "join the group":

```
chat.server.join("group1FixedName");
```

Code in Hub for joining:

```
public Task Join(string groupName)
{
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName)
               .ContinueWith(z => Clients.Caller.showCallerMessage("You are now listening to " + groupName));

}
```

Is there something wrong with my implementation here?

Comment: The snippets you show look fine. Can you make a sample application and  put it on github?

Comment: Thanks @dfowler, I'll make a scaled down version of my application, and make sure I replicate the issue first.

Comment: I uploaded the sample applications here: https://github.com/ericpanorel/SignalrDebugForDfowler While debugging, I found that the beta bits on the self-host application still worked (no problem), even if I had the latest bits for the client. When I upgraded the bits for the self-hosted app as well, the problem described appears already.

Answer (score 0):

This is bug #2040 introduced in 1.1.0beta.
Team is working on fixing it.